# Avoiding Scientific Notation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to avoid scientific notation. I get given a random number and have to calculate the factorial of that number. I think I have figured it out however when the number is longer than 16 digits it doesn't print the number completely.

For example, if I want to calculate the factorial of 30 I would want it to return as 265,252,859,812,191,058,636,308,480,000,000. Instead I get 2.652528598121911e+32.

This is the code that I'm using to calculate it:

```
 function zeros (n) {
  let total = 1;

  for(let i = n; i > 0; i--){
    total = i * total;
  }

  return total;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript numbers don’t have enough precision to store the exact value 265,252,859,812,191,058,636,308,480,000,000. You can ask for it not to be formatted in scientific notation, but the value will be wrong (265,252,859,812,191,**104,246,398,737,973,248**). If you’re trying to count the trailing zeros in a factorial, you should try coming up with a smarter way (it exists).

Comment: JS cannot really handle numbers when they go too large. You either need to use a library that handles big numbers for you like [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) or you will need to make the functionality yourself. The latter is really annoying - you will need to represent numbers as something else, like strings and then do custom mathematical operations that use strings instead of numeric types.

Comment: BigInt solves this problem. (but it didn't exist when you guys were commenting this question). Chrome adopted BigInt in version 67, in May 28, 2018. Just 26 days after these comments were made in this question. Firefox only adopted BigInt in version 68 (July, 2019). Today all major browsers can deal with extremely large integers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt